# Django psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Tags: python, django

The unit tests started to crash  with `django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed`. After I switched to Postgres. I found a few solves in at https://www.djangoproject.com/ page but it did not help. .

Python 3.6
Django 3.0.7
Postgres 10.12

Test case :

```
class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = RequestsClient()
        self.url = HOST + '/api/token/'
        self.headers = {}
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(**random_user)

    def test_login_correct(self):
        try:
            r = self.client.post(self.url, data={
                'email': random_user['email'],
                'password': random_user['password']
            }).json()

        except JSONDecodeError:
            self.fail("/api/token endpoint for POST request not implemented correctly")

        self.assertTrue('access' in r)
        self.assertTrue('refresh' in r)
```

Trace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 238, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 231, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\accounts\tests\tests.py", line 141, in setUp
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(**random_user)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\accounts\models.py", line 33, in create_user
    **extra_fields)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\accounts\models.py", line 28, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1390, in execute_sql
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 238, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 238, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Work\FarmerRest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 231, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: Where is the `TestCase` imported from?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is probably that you are using `TestCase` instead of `TransactionTestCase`. This is a common occurrence as soon as you use async code, which from your backtrace seems to be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer isn't getting lots of love. It's the only answer that actually fixed the problem for me after googling around for an hour!

Comment: This still seems to be a problem and the trade-off is far slower tests, so if anyone stumbles upon a fix to use TestCase, would be glad to know about it